Не загружаются пакеты NuGet в WPF
Мне нужно установить пакет Material Design для работы на WPF. Устанавливал пакет и через NuGet расширение непосредственно, и через Package Manager Console. При установке через консоль вылетало такое сообщение:

Не удалось обновить перенаправления привязок для WpfApp1.csproj:
Адресат вызова создал исключение.

При запуске проекта бросается исключение:

System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException: ""Задание свойства
"System.Windows.ResourceDictionary.Source" вызвало исключение.": номер
строки "10" и позиция в строке "18"."
IOException: Не удается найти ресурс "themes/materialdesigntheme.defaults.xaml".

Вот код в App.xaml
<Application x:Class="WpfApp1.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf;component/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.Light.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf;component/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.Defaults.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignColors;component/Themes/Recommended/Primary/MaterialDesignColor.DeepPurple.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignColors;component/Themes/Recommended/Accent/MaterialDesignColor.Lime.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>

В соответствие с тем, что на сайте http://materialdesigninxaml.net. Вообще проблема в том, что найти ресурсы не может, но я разными способами переустанавливал пакет уже, не помогает

версия .NET какая? версия пакета какая?

@aepot .net framework 4.7.2, MaterialDesignThemes - 5.0.0, MaterialDesignColors - 3.0.0

Адресат вызова создал исключение. - какое?

Есть ли какой-то глубокий смысл в использовании устаревшего .NET Framework 4.7.2? Почему не .NET 6 например или свежее?

@aepot глубокого смысла нет, за исключением того что, я просто учусь пока на .net framework. Я видео урок смотрел 3 летней давности, где все это работало, поэтому может на данный момент действительно уже устарело. Под .NET вы имеете в виду .NET Core же?

@EvgeniyZ скорее всего то, что ниже описано. В консоли Package Manager Console другой информации об ошибке нет

.NET 8.0 актуальная версия .NET, и да, это наследник .NET Core. Судя по библиотеке, вам идеально подошел бы .NET 6.0

Я надеюсь вы понимаете, что пришли сюда сейчас и говорите "У меня ошибка, как решить?", но саму ошибку нам не даете, даете только заголовок в котором написано "Произошла ошибка". И вот вы просите у нас помощи... Надеюсь вы понимаете, что вам невозможно дать ответа без самой ошибки? У вас там может быть все, что угодно, от левых настроек студии, до отсутствия доступа к NuGet (VPN в помощь)... Так что, давайте вы всеж поищите ошибку и дадите ее нам. В окне вывода если что есть переключатель, где есть пункт "Диспетчер пакетов", ошибка может быть там.

Я полгода назад делал проект на wpf с использованием materialdesign, .net framework 4.7.2,  а версия materialdesignthemes 4.9.0, materialdesigncolors 2.1.4. Устанавливал из пакетов Nuget (не через консоль, а просто в поиске пакетов нашел и нажал установить). Resourse dictionary как у тебя описан. Возможно дополнительно тебе стоит дописать какие то строки в xaml файле, именно в атрибутах окна, у меня написана вот такая строка xmlns:materialDesign="http://materialdesigninxaml.net/winfx/xaml/themes".

У меня возникла точно такая же проблема. Просто замените версию библиотеки на ту, что была в видео. В моём случае пришлось изменить версию библиотеки materialdesign c 5.0.0 до версии 3.2.0 после чего программа заработала
